# Shield UI grid wrong value on edit whe grouping

Tags: javascript, grid, grouping, edit, shieldui

I am testing this grid. It has several interesting features. But doing something very basic I find a problem that makes it practically unusable.

When the grid is grouped. If I try to edit any record, the value that is displayed in the editable field does not correspond to the record. Afterwards all the data in the registry is lost.

[Here is a codepen](https://codepen.io/ariel-larraburu/pen/xmZPOJ)

```
[https://codepen.io/ariel-larraburu/pen/xmZPOJ][1]
```

HTML:

```
<div id="grid"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
   jQuery(function ($) {
        $("#grid").shieldGrid({
            dataSource: {
                data: gridData,    
                schema: {
                          fields: window.orderFields = {
                            "name": {path: "name", type: String},  
                            "company": {path: "company", type: String},  
                            "email": {path: "email", type: String}  
                          }
                        },
                group: [{ field: "company", order: "asc" }]
            },
        rowHover: false,
        sorting: {
            multiple: false
        },
        selection: {
            type: "row",
            multiple: false,
            toggle: false
        },
        grouping: {
            showGroupHeader: true,
            allowDragToGroup: true,
            message: "Arrastrar aqui para agrupar"
        },
        scrolling: true,
        columnReorder: true,
        resizing: true,
        filtering: {
            enabled: true
        },
            columns: [                
                { field: "id", width: "70px", title: "ID", editable: true, groupFooterTemplate: "Cant. : {count}" },
                { field: "name", title: "Person Name", editable: true, groupFooterTemplate: "Cant. : {count}" },
                { field: "company", title: "Company Name", editable: true, groupFooterTemplate: "Cant. : {count}" },
                { field: "email", title:"Email Address", width: "270px", editable: true, groupFooterTemplate: "Cant. : {count}" }
            ],
        editing: {
            enabled: true,
            event: "doubleclick",
            type: "cell"
        }          
        });
    });
```

Comment: double click to enter on edit mode...